# cx_freeze: DLL load failed while importing win32ui

Tags: python, dll, cx-freeze, pywin32, win32gui

I wanted to distribute my Python project with cx_freeze. But when executing the exe-file I get error message mentioned in the title: DLL load failed while importing win32ui.

I've already tried some solutions that are posted here like including the "Pythonwin"-folder and the two dll-files in the distribution folder or using "py2exe" instead but none of them worked. Although the "win32ui.pyd", "mfcm140u.dll" and the "mfc140u.dll" are in the "lib"-folder of the distribution.

This is my py-file that I want to have distributed: https://github.com/DeatorFM/Redemption-Tracker

And this is the setup.py I prepared:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
# "packages": ["os"] is used as example only
# build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# base="Win32GUI" should be used only for Windows GUI app
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "RedTrack",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "App um Einlösungen von Kanalpunkten zu tracken",
    executables = [Executable("Redempttracker_UI.py", base=base)]
)
```

I'm grateful for every suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved!**

I tried to use pyinstaller in debugging-mode instead and apparently pywintypes39.dll was missing so I included it in the dist file.